# didSelectRowAt not triggering (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've tried looking up other responses, and none of them seem to help. Also, this is in Swift 5 and many of the other responses I see are for older versions.

My issue: **My tableView cells don't react consistently. Sometimes they respond to `didSelectRowAt`, sometimes they don't. So why is it that *sometimes* I can tap a cell and get it to respond, and other times I can't? It's not even the same cell every time, and if I dismiss and recall the table, it may be different cells or the same ones.**

My `configureCell` function works without issue. (I know it's not the problem, because I've tried setting things both with and without the function.)

**What I've tried**

1) I've tried both setting and not setting:

- `tableView.delegate = self`
- `tableView.dataSource = self`
- `tableView.allowsSelection = true`
- `tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

And I've tried setting the `allowsSelection` or `isUserInteractionEnabled` both at the `tableView` level and the `tableViewCell` level.

2) I've quadruple checked that `User Interaction Enabled` is turned on at the cell level, and "Single Selection" is turned on at the table level.

3) I've even tried removing all other code on the `didSelectRowAt` function except for a `print()` function just to make sure it wasn't my code, and sometimes it would call, other times it wouldn't, with no rhyme or reason.

Is it possible that it's my computer, and not my code that's the problem? I'm running `macOS Catalina 10.15.2` with `Xcode 11.3`.

**Here's my code:**

For reference, the `RoundScoreType` is a class with 2 variables: `var name: String` and `var isSelected: Bool`. `RoundScoreMenu` is a class with some functions in it, but basically is a place holder for 2 arrays of `RoundScoreType` with 5 entries each and some functions that I'm not calling yet, other than the `tallyScore` function, which hasn't been a problem. (Once again, tried both with and without the function, and no appreciable difference)

```
protocol ScoreTableDelegate {
    func scoreTableDelegate(team1Score: Int, team2Score: Int, round: Int)
}

class ScoreTableTVC: UITableViewController {

    var team1Name = "Team 1"
    var team2Name = "Team 2"
    var team1List = RoundScoreMenu().team1List
    var team2List = RoundScoreMenu().team2List

    var team1RoundScore: Int = 0
    var team2RoundScore: Int = 0

    var round: Int?
    var delegate: ScoreTableDelegate?

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, item: RoundScoreType){
        cell.textLabel!.text = item.name
        if item.isSelected {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        delegate?.scoreTableDelegate(team1Score: team1RoundScore, team2Score: team2RoundScore, round: round!)
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 5
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0 {
            return team1Name + ": " + String(team1RoundScore.description)
        } else {
            return team2Name + ": " + String(team2RoundScore.description)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ScoreCell", for: indexPath)
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            configureCell(cell: cell, item: team1List[indexPath.row])
        } else {
            configureCell(cell: cell, item: team2List[indexPath.row])
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.isSelected = true
        print("Section: \(indexPath.section), row: \(indexPath.row)")
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            team1List[indexPath.row].toggleSelection()
        } else {
            team2List[indexPath.row].toggleSelection()
        }
        tallyScore(indexPath.section)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.isSelected = true` - You shouldn't need to do that although I can't see it causing the specific problem.

Comment: is there any button inside the cell?

Comment: @ChrisShaw: Yeah, didn't have that originally, thought it couldn't hurt to add it if it would force the event.

Comment: @ShivamParmar: No buttons. Using basic cells and only accessing the label and accessory during configuration.

Comment: @DWShore Hmmm, you say you have single selection turned on for the table and you are using the `didSelectRowAt` as a toggle of your own state. Do you need to include `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)` in the `didSelectRowAt` implementation?

Comment: @ChrisShaw: I don't think I need it, but when I was learning how to set it up, they suggested doing that makes it so whatever cell is tapped doesn't stay selected. I've tried without it too and it hasn't made a difference yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it worked or made a difference, but I flipped the `tableView` selection option from "Single Selection" to "Multiple Selection" and all of a sudden, it worked. It could still be that it was a problem with my computer compiling it, but that is the last thing I changed and it suddenly started working.

Thanks for the help!